# Spark read CSV - Not showing corroupt Records

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Spark has a `Permissive` mode for reading `CSV` files which stores the corroupt records into a separate column named `_corroupt_record`.

> permissive  -
>   Sets all fields to null when it encounters a corrupted record and places all corrupted records in a string column
>   called _corrupt_record

However, when I am trying following example, I don't see any column named `_corroupt_record`. the reocords which doesn't match with schema appears to be `null`

**data.csv**

```
data
10.00
11.00
$12.00
$13
gaurang
```

**code**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructField, StructType, StringType, LongType, DecimalType}
val schema = new StructType(Array(
new StructField("value", DecimalType(25,10), false)
))
val df = spark.read.format("csv") 
  .option("header", "true") 
  .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE") 
  .schema(schema) 
  .load("../test.csv")
```

**schema**

```
scala> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- value: decimal(25,10) (nullable = true)


scala> df.show()
+-------------+
|        value|
+-------------+
|10.0000000000|
|11.0000000000|
|         null|
|         null|
|         null|
+-------------+
```

If I change the mode to `FAILFAST` I am getting error when I try to see data.

Comment: You have to add _corrupt_record to your schema.

Comment: add("_corrupt_record", StringType, true) // The schema contains a special column _corrupt_record, which does not exist in the data. This column captures rows that did not parse correctly. See https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/_static/notebooks/read-csv-corrupt-record.html

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `_corroup_record` as suggested by Andrew and Prateek resolved the issue.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructField, StructType, StringType, LongType, DecimalType}
val schema = new StructType(Array(
  new StructField("value", DecimalType(25,10), true),
  new StructField("_corrupt_record", StringType, true)
))
val df = spark.read.format("csv") 
  .option("header", "true") 
  .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE") 
  .schema(schema) 
  .load("../test.csv")
```

**querying Data**

```
scala> df.show()
+-------------+---------------+
|        value|_corrupt_record|
+-------------+---------------+
|10.0000000000|           null|
|11.0000000000|           null|
|         null|         $12.00|
|         null|            $13|
|         null|        gaurang|
+-------------+---------------+
```