# How to infer a schema from a "reference file" and apply it as a reference to files to be read in?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have tons of csv-Files to read into Spark (Databricks) with 100+ columns. I do not want to specify the schema manually and have thought of using the following way. Read in a "reference" csv File, get the schema from this file and apply it as "reference_schema" to all other files I need to read in. Code would look as follows (but I cannot get it to work).

```
# File location and type
file_location = "/FileStore/tables/reference_file_with_ok_schema.csv"
file_type = "csv"

# CSV options
infer_schema = "True"
first_row_is_header = "True"
delimiter = ";"

df = spark.read.format(file_type) \
  .option("inferSchema", infer_schema) \
  .option("header", first_row_is_header) \
  .option("sep", delimiter) \
  .load(file_location)

mySchema = df.schema ###this is probably where I go wrong

display(df)
```

Next I would apply mySchema as the reference Schema for new csv's like in the following example:

```
# File location and type
file_location = "/FileStore/tables/all_other_files.csv"
file_type = "csv"

# CSV options
first_row_is_header = "True"
delimiter = ";"

# The applied options are for CSV files. For other file types, these will be ignored.
df = spark.read.format(file_type) \
  .schema(mySchema) \
  .option("header", first_row_is_header) \
  .option("sep", delimiter) \
  .load(file_location)

display(df)
```

This only produces nulls

Thanks in advance for your help and
best regards
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right approach.

You can check these two options `mode` and `columnNameOfCorruptRecord`. By default, `mode=PERMISSIVE` which creates NULL records when line does not match schema.
That is probably why you have NULL records in you dataframe, it means the schema `mySchema` and the schema of file `all_other_files` are different.

The first thing to check is to infer the schema of `all_other_files` and compare it with `mySchema`. To do that easily, `schema` object have a `json` method which output them as JSON string. It is easier for human to compare two jsons than 2 schema objects.

```py
mySchema.json()
```

If there is just one difference, the whole line will be set to NULL unfortunately.

Comment: Hi Steven, you seem to be right. In one column all values have been of a different type. What is odd, that the **columnNameOfCorruptRecord** does not show up in the dataframe. The original columns are all there with NULL, but the additional "corrupt" column is missing. Any idea?

Comment: @DocAl If you do not set anything, it uses the value specified in `spark.sql.columnNameOfCorruptRecord`. Maybe, this value is also empty, therefore, there is not corrupt column in the output. But you can manually set it in your options. Check the params available in [csv](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv) method.

Comment: I did explicitly set it with **.option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "row_corrupt")**. Might not show because I am using a schema? Best Alex

Comment: @DocAl apparently, you need to add the column to the original schema. `mySchema.add(field, data_type=None, nullable=True, metadata=None)`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631365/spark-read-csv-not-showing-corroupt-records

Comment: Added the field and it seems to work now. Still have to test, but many thanks Steven. Best Alex